# PFSense: Internal server don't see the real ip, only the ip of the gateway pfsense

Tags: firewall, routing, pfsense

I'm trying to use a pfsense as a substitute of our hosting centers cisco gateway on my testbed for testing our new firewall

The setup is:
[Internet]->[Wan: ?? -Hosting Center Router- Lan: 85.10.100.1] -> [Wan: 85.10.100.2/30 -Our firewall-  DMZ:85.10.100.253/24] -> [Network of machines with 85.10.100.x adresses]

We do not have access or very much knowledge of this cisco gateway other than it's used as gateway for all our machines who all have ip adresses defined in the mentioned 85 range

The pfsense is sat as substituting the cisco gateway, with a couple of clients on the WAN side of the pfsense with random ip's

I have disabled NAT, and made a allow any, any rule in the firewall part (else nothing works) and my clients can ping the machines on the inside network.

But the problem is when a client is accessing ex. a webserver on port 80 on one of the 85 machines, if you look in the access_log - the request is coming from the pfsense lan ip (85.10.100.1), and not the actual ip.

What do i miss?

(the 85 network definition is made up, but it resembles the actual ip's)

Answer (score 1):

Either you have a proxy running on the box, or you haven't really disabled NAT. 
http://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/How_can_I_completely_disable_NAT%3F#Disable_NAT